# iOS LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication "Cancel" Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I'm currently using LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication in my app to bring up TouchID/Passcode verification. However, if the user clicks "Cancel", my app just closes the touchID/Passcode verification and does nothing. Is there a way I can get it to reboot the touchID verification process again?

Here is what I'm currently attempting to do:

```
-(void)callAuthenticate {
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Please Enter Touch ID";

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showList" sender:nil];
                                });
                            } else if (error){
                                NSString *errorMessage;
                                BOOL showError = NO;
                                switch (error.code) {
                                    case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                                        errorMessage = @"Sorry couldn't autheticate";
                                        showError = YES;
                                        break;
                                    case LAErrorPasscodeNotSet:
                                        errorMessage = @"No Passcode has been set";
                                        showError = YES;
                                        break;
                                    case LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled:
                                        errorMessage = @"Touch ID has no enrolled fingers";
                                        showError = YES;
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        showError = NO;
                                        break;
                                }
                                if (showError) {
                                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                    message:errorMessage
                                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                    [alert show];

                                }
                            }
                        }];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showList" sender:nil];
}
```

}

Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the case when the error code is `LAErrorUserCanceled`. Currently that is being handled by the `default:` case which does nothing.